# XSS JavaScript Double Quoted String with HTML Escaped Possible?

Tags: javascript, xss

Is it possible to inject XSS in a JavaScript variable if a website inserts HTML encoded, user input in a double quoted string?

`var userString = "perfectly &quot;safe&quot; input from user?";`

Comment: Depends on what you're going to do with the string.

Comment: If nothing done with it and in script tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably not possible to get XSS given this simple character restriction.  However, an attacker could inject an escape character,  for example:

```
var userString = "perfectly &quot;safe&quot; input from user?\"+"+alert(1);
```

In this case the attacker would be injecting a `\` and an `alert(1)` in two different variables which existing in two locations within the `<script>` tag.  Escape characters are a type of control character that are commonly forgotten by developers when sanitizing attacker controlled data.

...  also hopefully you took this into consideration:

```
<script>
var userString = "</script><script>alert(1)//"
</script>
```

Comment: In the second example, if `"` is encoded into `&quot;`, I hope `<` and `>` are too!

Comment: @minitech  the op failed to mention such a critical detail!

Comment: HTML encoding includes `&lt; &amp; &gt;`, but good to know for completeness.

Comment: @user27675  Yes,  any character can be HTML encoded,  as the HEX format `&#xhhhh; ` supports all of ASCII and even Unicode!  However, you did not mention what HTML encode function you used.